# How to catch ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception during save()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got a Users table with an Email column in my database. I've also created a UNIQUE index on the Email column to prevent two users from registering the same email address (note: please don't suggest that I use `validates_uniqueness_of` since this is what I'm trying to avoid).

When I run run my RSpec test to make sure that a duplicate record cannot be inserted, I see the following error:

```
Failures:
  1) User should not allow duplicate email addresses
     Failure/Error: user2.save.should_not be_true
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
       SQLite3::ConstraintException: column email is not unique: INSERT INTO "users" ("email", ... ) VALUES ( ... )
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:26
```

This is good because it means that my UNIQUE index is indeed working. The question is, how can I handle this exception? I'd like to be able to catch it, then add a sensible message to the model's errors collection.

I've tried - unsuccessfully - using rescue_from in the controller as follows:

```
rescue_from 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique' do |ex|
    raise 'Email must be unique'
end
```

The Rails API docs don't appear to suggest how to override the save() method in order to add a begin/rescue block, so my question is this:  How can I handle the ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique exception that is being thrown during save() then mark the model as invalid and add a sensible error message to the model's errors collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class User
...
def save
 super
 rescue 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique' 
   logger.error($!.to_s) # or something like that.
 end
end
```

You can overload any action in your models and just call `super` to execute the inherited method definition

The Rails API prolly doesn't mention it because its an feature of Ruby, not just Rails.

Comment: When I try to use rescue_from in the model, I get the error: undefined method 'resuce_from'... We're using rails 3.0.7, so it should be available. It seems to be something that is only available in ApplicationController, not ActiveRecord.

Comment: sorry, was beign lazy with my copy and paste, that would just be a regular `rescue`  i'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks. I came up with something similar, based on your suggestion: def save
    begin
      super #invoke superclass save()
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
      #todo: improve error message?
      errors.add :email, 'That Email address is already in use'
      false
    end    
  end

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I have a table with an index using several fields up by wich the table is sorted

***at db/migrate***

```
class CreateDids < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :dids do |t|
      t.string :lada, null: false, limit: 3
      t.string :pre_did, null: false, limit: 4
      t.string :did, null: false, limit: 7
      t.boolean :uso_interno_ns, default: false, null: false

      t.timestamps
      t.integer :lock_version, null: false, default: 0
      t.index [:lada, :pre_did, :did], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

Now, to validate a unique mix of fields in ***models/did.rb*** I wrote:

```
  validates :lada, presence: true, length: { within: 1..3 }, numericality: { only_integer: true}
  validates :pre_did, presence: true, length: { within: 1..4 }, numericality: { only_integer: true}
  validates :did, presence: true, length: { within: 4..7 }, numericality: { only_integer: true}
  validate do
    errors.add :base,I18n.t('dids.numero_menor_10') unless 10 == ( self.lada + self.pre_did + self.did ).size if self.lada and self.pre_did and self.did
  end
```

But, it did not validate for duplicated mix of fields (lada+pre_did+did), so in ***models/did.rb*** also wrote:

```
def save
  begin
    super
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
    errors.add(:base,I18n.t('dids.telefono_duplicado'))
    false
  end
end

def update( x )
  begin
    super x
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
    errors.add(:base,I18n.t('dids.telefono_duplicado'))
    false
  end
end
```

Now in my case, if I do not return ***false*** after rescue, this does not work.